# How can I specify a gem to pull from a private github repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, github, heroku

I have a private repository on Github that I want to use. I deploy my app to Heroku. How can I specify a private repository as the source on my gemfile? I imagine it wouldn't be enough to simply say

```
gem "mygem", :git=>"my github address"
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As per suggestion from Heroku tech support, the easiest way to do this is by putting the username and password into the URL, as in Basic HTTP Auth, e.g.

```
gem 'my_gem', :git => 'https://my_username:my_password@github.com/my_github_account/my_repo.git', :ref => 'revision_no'
```

This worked for us. This is still somewhat dissatisfying as we had to put a password into the Gemfile. We dealt with this by adding a new github user account and adding that account as collaborator on the gem project. Still not foolproof security, but the impact is more narrow.

Other options I read about are to [set up your own gem server](http://olemortenamundsen.wordpress.com/2010/09/13/working-with-private-rubygems-in-rails-3-deploying-to-heroku/) or to [vendor the gem](http://underpantsgnome.com/2011/01/05/how-to-install-private-gems-on-heroku).

**Update 5/16/2012:**
Another way to get around putting the password into the `Gemfile` is to put the password into an environment variable; on Heroku you do this with `heroku config:add VAR=value`, and then in the `Gemfile` you'd use this variable, e.g.:

```
gem 'my_gem',
  :git => "https://#{ENV['var_private_gem_username']}:#{ENV['var_private_gem_password']}@github.com/my_github_account.git",
  :ref => 'rev'
```

This is the standard on Heroku to avoid putting passwords, API keys and any credentials into the code. For local development/test, you can set these environment variables. Or, assuming your development machine is set up for SSH access to github, you won't need the credentials for local development (the SSH credentials will be in effect already). So you could set up some conditional logic:

```
private_repo_credentials = %w(var_private_gem_username var_private_gem_password).
  map { |var| ENV[var] }.compact.join(':')
private_repo_credentials << '@' unless private_repo_credentials.empty?
# private_repo_credentials will be "" if neither var is set
# private_repo_credentials will be "username:password@" if they are set
gem 'my_gem',
  :git => "https://#{private_repo_credentials}github.com/my_github_account.git",
  :ref => 'rev'
```

I've not tested this last part. Please provide feedback.

Comment: For the ENV approach to work, you'll have to enable a labs addon: `heroku labs:enable user_env_compile`. Unfortunately, there are still issues with matching the Gemfile.lock.

Comment: You might also consider using Gemfury https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/gemfury

Comment: github has rolled out a new feature for this: https://github.com/blog/1270-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth

Comment: @WolframArnold...can we do this with unfuddle ?

Comment: @rubyprince if Unfuddle accepts credentials via HTTP Simple Auth, e.g. https://@<username>:<password>/<url> then you should get it to work. If they don't support simple auth over HTTPS you should definitely ask for that. They may also have a custom feature, like github now, see preceding comment.

Comment: There's an issue with user-env-compile and using the ENV in Gemfile - your password / token will still be in the Gemfile.lock Any way out?

Comment: I think the answer is using github's native feature.

Comment: I'm seeing my password in the Gemfile.lock even with the ENV variables. Dangerous solution

Comment: Ain't this why Github has deploy keys? Shouldn't we be using those?

Comment: Please don't do this. Don't put your credentials in the Gemfile. Even if you use environment variables, they will end up in the Gemfile.lock. See my answer below.

Answer (score 121):

The best way I've found to deploy a gem pulled from a private repo is to use [GitHub's OAuth access](https://github.com/blog/1270-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth). To do so:

1. Create a GitHub user with access to the repo in question (best for teams – if you're okay exposing your personal access tokens, you can simply use your own account).
2. Create an GitHub OAuth token for the user. It's dead simple to do this over the GitHub API just using `curl`; see [the OAuth API](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#oauth-authorizations-api) for more.
3. Add the token to the `git` url in your Gemfile. Example:

```
gem 'mygem', git: 'https://xxx123abc:x-oauth-basic@github.com/user_or_team/mygem.git'
```

I'm currently using this method on Heroku and it works great. The beauty is that you don't have to expose your own personal information, and you can revoke or regenerate the token at any point if something is compromised.

Comment: This worked for me. For more information on how to create the OAuth token, visit: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-oauth-token-for-command-line-use

Comment: Not sure why everyone is upvoting the answer that instructs you to put your password in plaintext into version control, then deploy it to a third-party website instead of this one.

Comment: You can now create personal OAuth tokens on the GitHub site: https://github.com/settings/tokens/new

Comment: This should be the accepted answer @picardo. Could you change it?

Comment: @picardo can you update the question to use this answer instead of the one you selected?

Comment: Take the time to create a new GitHub account that has nothing but read access to the Gem repo and scope the token to repo. Do not use access tokens for your own account, they will have all of your access.

Answer (score 29):

This question deserves a better answer since both the accepted answer and the most voted ones **ARE NOT SAFE** if you want to avoid putting your credentials or oauth token in the repository.

**Please don't do:**

```rb
gem 'my_private_gem', git: 'https://my_username:my_password@github.com/my_github_account/my_private_gem.git'
```

or

```rb
gem 'my_private_gem', git: 'https://xxx123abc:x-oauth-basic@github.com/my_github_account/my_private_gem.git'
```

**even if you move them as environment variables, they will still be written in your Gemfile.lock**.

the correct solution is to put the following on the Gemfile:

```rb
gem 'my_private_gem', git: 'https://github.com/my_github_account/my_private_gem.git'
```

and configure bundler to use your oauth key via:

```sh
export MY_OAUTH_KEY=abcd
bundle config github.com $MY_OAUTH_KEY
```

Create the oauth key [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new) with the `repo` scope.

You can now set the env variable `MY_OAUTH_KEY` on you machine, on the CI and on Heroku so that they can all download the gem.

On Heroku, you will set the following environment variable:

```
BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM: <your_oauth_key>
```

Comment: I didn't understand some things.

In which file I need to configure the bundler?
I need to set both BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM and MY_OAUTH_KEY on Heroku?

Comment: On Heroku you can set the environment variable BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM with your oauth key. You can set this env variable also locally if you want

Comment: This is best solid solution it should be accepted answer

Comment: This is the safest answer.  Is there any security issues with `export MY_OAUTH_KEY=abcd`, should you unset `$MY_OAUTH_KEY` after doing the `bundle config`

Comment: For anyone trying to use GitHub's new **fine-grained personal access tokens**, I got this to work by adding the **Contents** read-only repository permission, and then you need to prefix the token with `oauth2:` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74532853/6728018)

Answer (score 8):

I found that if I have access from my terminal to github ([by uploading an ssh key to github](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)), I can simply do:

```
gem 'my_gem', :git => 'git@github.com:my_user/my_repo.git', :ref => 'revision_no'
```

without polluting my code with my git username or password

Comment: @KhoaNguyen It won't work out of the box, since the Heroku server would try to access the git repository directly. I think it may be possible to add your Heroku server's ssh key to your github repository, thus allowing this access - **but I'm not sure its possible**

Comment: @gardenofwine, This approach may work if you have one or two servers on Heroku. On a larger scale, you cannot add keys from all your servers to Github.

Answer (score 4):

- Create a [ssh keys](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/)
- Make sure those keys under `~/.ssh` directory
- Copy content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` into https://github.com/MY_COMPANY/MY_GEM/settings/keys
- In your `Gemfile` use: `gem 'mygem', github: 'MY_COMPANY/MY_GEM'`
- run `bundle install`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @seth-bro's answer, we can also use `bundle config` to configure the credentials using bundler, so that we need not expose the oAuth token on the Gemfile.

Syntax: `bundle config github.com <your_github_oauth_token>`

Refer: https://gist.github.com/sebboh/f1dfe4f096746c45f3e9ea06a09743a0
https://bundler.io/v1.16/bundle_config.html

Answer (score 1):

The most secure way to do this is to configure the github personal token the following way. After you create your github personal access token by following their [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), do the following:

1. In your local machine, do:

> `bundle config github.com YOUR_GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN:x-oauth-basic`

2. In heroku, set `BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM` ENV variable:

> `BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM = YOUR_GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN`

You can also do this from your terminal by doing:

> `heroku config:set BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM=YOUR_GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN`

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully still relevant in 2015, you can use https://github.com/siassaj/heroku-buildpack-git-deploy-keys with a deploy key from github.

This way you avoid putting the username and pass into Gemfile, which will end up as plain text in the Gemfile.lock

Answer (score -3):

I found that when using the env approach and heroku labs:enable user_env_compile then there is no problem with the Gemfile.lock