# heroku + git submodule needs authentication

Tags: git, heroku, gitolite

We are using gitolite to manage our repositories and one of our heroku project's have git submodules. Is there a way to get Heroku's public key for the authentication?

Thanks, David

Comment: Wouldn't anyone using Heroku would be able to pull that submodule? Also, it's worth checking if Heroku has a public/private key available during slug compilation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, probably not. Instead, you can use HTTPS basic authentication when you create the submodule in your git repository, [similar to deploying private gems to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949955/687783). Looks something like this:

```
git submodule add https://username:password@github.com/username/repo.git
```

Comment: github has rolled out a new feature for this: https://github.com/blog/1270-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth

Comment: I tried this today and got this:

`fatal: I don't handle protocol 'git clone https'`

Comment: What did you type exactly?

Comment: the *submodule* folder in the `.git` directory has changed from `.git/submodules` to `.git/modules` in version 1.8.4. I think this breaks Heroku's deployment procedure

Comment: @Yasky, has Heroku fixed that?

Answer (score 3):

You can also commit a .ssh directory containing a dedicated id_rsa key ("deployment key") that is registered with github, either with your account or a dedicated deployment account. Don't forget to `chmod 0660` the key.

Comment: Where should the .ssh folder go?

Comment: There's a better solution now using a buildpack:

https://github.com/timshadel/heroku-buildpack-github-netrc

Answer (score 2):

There is another solution to @kanzure approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29464430/990356

Go to [Settings > Personal access tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and generate a personal access token with `repo` scope enabled.

Now you can do `git clone https://MY_TOKEN@github.com/user-or-org/repo` and in the case of a submodule `git submodule add https://MY_TOKEN@github.com/user-or-org/repo`

Pros:

- very simple approach
- token can be easily revoked
- your real password is safe

Cons:

- if someone has access to the token, he can access your GitHub repos (read and write)

Comment: Is this working? for me s not working at all