# rails 3 Duplicated Code Multiple Projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on multiple projects, which most of them have common controllers and views.

Is there a way to be able to copy all the common code in a script or something?

Any ideas on this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a rails engine, which is a gem you can use in other projects. The gem provides controllers, views, etc. [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is maybe one of the best examples of this, providing an authentication framework.

First promising hit on Google for how to make one was [this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/23/a-guide-to-starting-your-own-rails-engine-gem/), but I'm sure you can find more.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that it might be a gem route. However will this be a private gem as do want the code to available to the public?

I have my own Authentication Etc build from scratch!

Comment: "how to make a private gem" is another question entirely. :) If you're keeping your private gem in a local git repository, you can reference it that way from the `Gemfile`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840680/how-can-i-specify-a-gem-to-pull-from-a-private-github-repository is sort of about that.