# Rails 3.2: Could not find gem source when resolving dependency with bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, rubygems, bundler

After pointing `rails engine` to github, `bundle isntall` could be go through and generated error:

```
.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'task_templatex (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in
http://github.com/abc/task_templatex.git (at 3.2.12.01).
Source does not contain any versions of 'task_templatex (>= 0) x86-mingw32'
```

The `rails engine` was pointing to `github branch` in `Gemfile` like this:

```
gem 'task_templatex', :git => 'http://github.com/abc/task_templatex.git', :branch => '3.2.12.01'
```

After deleting `Gemfile.lock`, then the same error comes up saying that another engine gem could not be found at the source. Those 2 engine gems are out of total of 12 rails engines in the `Gemfile`. If removing those 2 gems from `Gemfile`, `bundle install` went well without error. Also when pointing gems to local drive, `bundle install` went well. What could cause the error?  Thanks.

BTW the same error shows up in both window 8 (develop) and ubuntu 12.04 (production).

Comment: Is it a private repo? Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840680/how-can-i-specify-a-gem-to-pull-from-a-private-github-repository

Comment: No, gem task_templatex is a public repo.

Comment: the gem works good if it's referenced locally?

Comment: Yes, no problem pointing to local drive.

Comment: Pretty dumb mistake! The gemspec was not uploaded to git. Error disappear after gemspec uploaded.