# Unable to bundle install a private gem with x-oauth-basic authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github

I use a gem, `my_gem` stored on github in an app, `my_app`. The `Gemfile` looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }
ruby '2.7.4'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.6'
...
gem 'my_gem', git: "https://#{ENV['PRIVATE_LIB_TOKEN']}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/obromios/my_gem.git", branch: 'master'
```

About a year ago, I was able to `bundle install` the app and push to `heroku` but this no longer works. I reissued an new private access token from Github, giving it access to the repo, and set it in my .env file as follows

```
PRIVATE_LIB_TOKEN=<token>
```

When I type `bundle install` I get the following error message

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/obromios/my_gem.git/'

Retrying `git clone https://x-oauth-basic@github.com/obromios/my_gem.git /Users/my_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/cache/bundler/git/my_gem-<some_other_token> --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` at /Users/my_name/xyz/my_app due to error (2/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone https://x-oauth-basic@github.com/obromios/my_gem.git /Users/my_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/cache/bundler/git/my_gem-<some_other_token> --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory my_app has failed.

If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/Users/my_name/xyz/my_app'
```

Looking at `/Users/my_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/cache/bundler/git/` there was a directory named my_gem-<yet_another_token>.  The tokens are all different but are random hashes of similar length.  I removed the `my_gem-<yet_another_token>` directory and this did not help. I also deleted `/Users/xyz/my_app` and reinstalled the app, but this did not work.

I note that since last time that this worked, I had set up two factor authentication on Github.

How do I fix this?

Comment: this solution should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64246000/13088705

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer to the question, but does provide a workaround as suggested by [Sachin Sing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13088705/sachin-singh).  This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64246000/1299362) points out that accessing the gem using a command like

```
gem 'my_gem', git: "https://#{ENV['PRIVATE_LIB_TOKEN']}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/obromios/my_gem.git"
```

causes the token to be written to the `Gemfile.lock` and so appears in the repository. It is suggested a better way is to put the following in the `Gemfile`

```
gem 'my_gem', git: "https://github.com/obromios/my_gem.git", branch: 'master'
```

and then doing the following

```
export MY_OAUTH_KEY=<token>
bundle config github.com $MY_OAUTH_KEY
```

This allowed me to bundle install the `Gemfile`.  In order to deploy to heroku, I needed to set the following config variable

```
heroku config:set BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM=<token>
```

Then I can just deploy the app to heroku and the gem is installed properly.

Comment: `bundle config github.com $MY_OAUTH_KEY` doesn't work. But, this does: `bundle config github.com YOUR_GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN:x-oauth-basic`, so I added a new answer for anyone who comes to this page to solve this issue :-)